# What benefits would I see upgrading from 14.04 to 15.04 and what are some caveats?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 15.04

What benefits would I see upgrading from 14.04 to 15.04 and what are some caveats? My system is pretty solid running on a dual core i5, 8gb, 512ssd, hd3000. I'm a newer Linux user and I don't do a lot of CLI foo, only How To's that seem interesting. Any thoughts on this issue? Should this be asked in the chat?

Comment: I was not aware that 15.04 is not an LTS, I assumed that since the designation "14.04" (meaning .04) was an LTS that 15."04" would be an LTS as well. So Ubuntu only offers LTS versions every 2 years, rather than a yearly basis. So IMO this wouldn't be a dupe, as I was asking for the benefits and caveats of upgrading from one version to another.

Comment: As far a myself accepting his answer, I only want to use LTS's, after reading other users having great difficulty making basic functions work properly in 15.04.

Comment: @David Foerster the question I asked refers to what benefits I would see upgrading, such as new software, tweaks that improve upon the existing version. NOT what the difference between an LTS and a STR.

Comment: I forgot to mention to you how the numbering works for the versions.  The `14` before the . means the year released `2014`.  And the `04` after the . means the month `04 = April`.  I didn't see if that was answered for you or not, so I am just passing the info on.

Comment: Thanks I've only been using Linux for 3 months. Basically since I got the computer for free and it was a windows machine and I'm a Mac guy I thought I'd try Linux just for fun. So now I know how the numbering works. I just use it as a machine to surf since my teenagers are using my 3 Macs and I find myself using the iPad or my iPhone as a last resort which is ok but you're kind of limited to what you can do. I find Linux somewhat complicated but I am learning. I doubt that I'll ever switch from Mac to Linux permanently, but it is useful. The best Linux app for me is btsync, great for sharing!

Comment: You are exactly right.  Linux / Ubuntu does have a learning curve to it.  I love learning new things, so I have jumped at the chance to learn all I can about Linux.  I used to be an Apple Certified Technician for 9 years, and I did standard desktop support for all the years.  I love the stability of Linux, and the fact that I can compile it the way I want to.  There are distros that allow you to design your own, but I recommend learning first.  Hey, we all have to start somewhere.  :)  Have a great day!

Comment: You as well. Terrance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ubuntu 14.04 was released as an LTS (Long Term Support) where it is stable, and the patches / updates will continue for years.  Ubuntu 15.04 is a non-LTS release, and will only be supported for a short time, like a only a few months.  I prefer the LTS releases for my everyday usage system, and when I want to test things out I use the non-LTS releases to check out the newer features that can be in future releases.  I just have to remember that non-LTS are not stable, and can be prone to crashes and very little hardware support.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Great! So when is the next LTS going to be released? 16.04? I'll keep Trusty since it works well now. I don't want to foobar my system. This is my free computer experiment with Ubuntu.

Comment: @Todd I would say 16.04 would be the next LTS, as it has been every 2 years for the release.

Comment: @Todd you're welcome!  You have a great weekend too!